# Browser's Back & Forward Buttons Don't Work After History.pushState()

Tags: javascript

I have a simple `history.pushState()` in my code:

```
history.pushState(null,null,data["url"]);
```

And it works perfectly, but when I click the browser's back button after running `history.pushState()`, only the URL bar changes; the page it's self does not reload.

I reviewed [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965031/history-pushstate-and-clicking-back-forward-button) [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22751023/history-pushstate-fails-browser-back-and-forward-button) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16435291/history-pushstate-with-back-and-forward-buttons) where this problem had been presented but none of the solutions in these answers solved my problem. I do not have any other `history` calls in my code, but for an identical call elsewhere. I'm not using `window.onpopstate` either and would prefer not to, unless absolutely necessary.

I noticed that in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18751040/5931472), the author suggested checking the address bar for changed every 500ms, then loading new content. This seems like a rather in-elegant solution and, though I would if there *is* no other way, I'd prefer not to use it (I'm worried about the effect it might have on performance).

Answer (score 0):

Well, for start - why not using onpopstate?* this is the right way to do it, as far as I understand.

_

*or, bind('popstate')